# How to know when two threads are finished in Swing

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have to perform two tasks. I like two threads perform each task simultaneously. The tasks don't share data.

Before the tasks start, is shown a dialog with a info "Wait, processing...".

Here the codes:

```
final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(this, true);
SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
      // Do the job
      return null;
   }
   @Override
   protected void done() {
      // Must close dialog? The other finished?
   }
};

SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker2 = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
      // Do the job
      return null;
   }
   @Override
   protected void done() {
      // Must close dialog? The other finished?
   }
};

worker.execute();
worker2.execute();
dialog.setVisible(true);
// Must close dialog?
```

I would like to close the dialog only when the two threads ended. How to know when they ended? Who and when should close the dialog?

**Update:** the threads must run simultaneously, not in sequential mode.

Comment: how many dialog box it shows 2 or 3 ??

Comment: Only one. I dont know when the two threads finish. Only when the threads are ended the dialog must closed...

Comment: Then call `worker2.execute()` in done method of first `worker` and close the `dialog` in `done` method of `worker2`.

Comment: But then is executed in sequential mode, or no?

Comment: Correct in the case of Vigahnesh it is then executed in 2 sequential threads. This would just keep the UI responsive

Comment: As your code seems you want to execute the threads one by one so it will run them in sequential way. See the answer I have posted.

Comment: Sorry, i edited the question with the information about the simultaneity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create a `CountDownLatch`, set to `2`
- Create your two `SwingWorkers`, passing each a reference to the `CountDownLatch`. In there `done` methods, call `countDown` on the latch. Do this in the `done` method, as it will be called regardless of how the `doInBackground` method exited (ie in case it throws an `Exception`)
- Create a third `SwingWorker`, passing it a reference to the `CountDownLatch`, in this worker wait for the latch in the `doInBackground` method.  Once this `SwingWorker`'s done method is called, you should now be able to dispose of the dialog safely

Comment: Re "Create a third SwingWorker", What happens if Swing is using only one worker thread?  Is there any way that Swing could choose to execute the task that waits for the count to reach zero before executing one or both of the tasks that decrement it?  It could take a loooong time for the count to reach zero if that happened.

Comment: SwingWorker is currently setup to execute up 10 workers at a time. I don't know of any circumstance that it would configured to only run one ... It would defeat the purpose, however, if that was the case, you could use a Thread of your own, you just become responsible for synchronizing the call to dispose on the EDT

Comment: @jameslarge The method by which the SwingWorker schedules threads are private/final and can only be changed by changing the core API itself. Do you have a circumstance where you've encountered a case that SwingWorker uses a single thread?

Comment: No, I was just asking. I don't have much experience with Swing, but I can't resist looking at software and trying to imagine all of the different ways it could go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like a counting lock for this. It is definitely using the least possible resources. The class below is a counting lock. Basically you initialise it with the constructor and specify the number of threads you need to wait for.

In the main thread (or UI thread) you call "waitForAll()" once you are done with setup. You can see that waitForAll is basically waiting for a notify from any other thread. If a notify is received it checks whether or not the number of active workers has reached zero. If the number of active workers is still greater 0 it waits again.

The workers however call unlock() on the lock. Notify decreases the counter by one and calls notify() which makes the main thread wake up and perform the above mentioned procedure.

```
public class CountingLock {

    private int counter;

    /**
     * Number of workers
     * 
     * @param n
     */
    public CountingLock(int n) {
        this.counter = n;
    }

    /**
     * Wait until counter == 0
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    public synchronized void waitForAll() throws InterruptedException {
        while(counter > 0) {
            this.wait();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deduce counter and notify
     */
    public synchronized void unlock() {
        this.counter--;
        this.notify();
    }

}
```

In the dialog prior launching the threads do the following:

```
CountingLock lock = new CountingLock(2);

/** put your thread setup code from your example here */

lock.waitForAll();
dialog.setVisible(false);
```

Make sure to pass a reference of lock to your threads and at the end of each thread call the following:

```
lock.unlock();
```

As per the comment to this answer, Java as of Java 1.5 (verified) provides a class java.concurrent.CountDownLatch with the exactly same behaviour. The use is well documented in the API.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html

**example with CoundDownLatch**

```
CountDownLatch lock = new CountDownLatch(2);

/** put your thread setup code from your example here */

lock.await();
dialog.setVisible(false);
```

In the threads do the following:

```
lock.countDown();
```

**full example**

```
final CountingLock lock = new CountingLock(2);
final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(this, true);
SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
      // Do the job
      return null;
   }
   @Override
   protected void done() {
      // Must close dialog? The other finished?
      lock.unlock();
   }
};

SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker2 = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
      // Do the job
      return null;
   }
   @Override
   protected void done() {
      // Must close dialog? The other finished?
      lock.unlock();
   }
};

worker.execute();
worker2.execute();
dialog.setVisible(true);
lock.waitForAll();
dialog.setVisible(false);
```

Actually you should also consider to move the waitForAll or await call and setting dialog.setVisible(false) in another background thread since you most likely will not want the UI to stall.

Comment: Good answer, however java.concurrent.CountDownLatch provides this already... since Java 6 I believe.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I added your suggestions to the answer.

Comment: Apologies, since Java 7, can't believe it took so long for such "basic" functionality :)

Comment: Hi, this is only after a brief check. Unfortunately the urls for Java API constantly change. This is why I put verified in braces to signal that I veri only for Java 7. It was definitely there since 1.5, will check how far back this was added.

Comment: *"main thread (or UI thread) you call "waitForAll()""* so now you're  suggesting the op block the EDT, which defeats the purpose of using the SwingWorker in the first place? I would agree, a Thread "controller" worker or Thread which was used to monitor the lock, but you'd have to synchronise the call to dispose of the dialog with the EDT

Comment: If I didn't, do you think the op would?

Answer (score 0):

You should [call get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#get--) on both workers

Comment: But the `get()` isnt a lock command? Then will be a sequential execution?

Comment: From the link I sent you: "Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result. "

Comment: Get is also a blocking call, which would block the EDT, defeating the purpose of using the SwingWorkers in the first place

Answer (score 0):

For now I have made a sample code which will help you to understand the logic behind this.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
public class DemoTest {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel();
    JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel();
    SwingWorker<Void,Void> worker1 = new SwingWorker<Void,Void>()
    {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

            for(int i = 0;i<=100;i++)
            {
                lbl1.setText("Counter1 Value:"+Integer.toString(i));
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done()
        {
            lbl1.setText("Thread 1 completed its job");
            worker2.execute();
        }
    };
    SwingWorker<Void,Void> worker2 = new SwingWorker<Void,Void>()
    {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

            for(int i = 0;i<=100;i++)
            {
                lbl2.setText("Counter1 Value:"+Integer.toString(i));
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done()
        {
            lbl2.setText("Thread 2 completed its job");

        }
    };
    public DemoTest()
    {
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(lbl1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(lbl2,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        try
        {
            worker1.execute();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //close dialog box
    }
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        DemoTest d = new DemoTest();
    }

}
```